# Remove all string items from a list, that are prefix of other string items in the list

Tags: python, algorithm, prefix-tree

I've got a list fo paths, and I'd like to keep only the items that are not prefix of any other item.

For example, In the following list:

```
private
private/etc
private/etc/pam.d
usr
usr/local
usr/local/lib
usr/local/lib/security
```

I want to keep only:

```
private/etc/pam.d
usr/local/lib/security
```

I prefer not to "invent the wheel" and implement prefix tree, but using a python package that already do this.

thanks!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonpath or https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list is already ordered, each item is a prefix of the following OR is not a prefix of any of the following.

Therefore, you can write:

```
ls.sort()
[ls[i] for i in range(len(ls))[:-1] if ls[i] != ls[i+1][:len(ls[i])]] + [ls[-1]]
```

Another implementation, using zip:

```
[x for x, y in zip(ls[:-1], ls[1:]) if x != y[:len(x)]] + [ls[-1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any packages, but this should do it:

```
#a is the list of items
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i, len(a)):
        if (a[i] in a[j]) and len(a[i]) < len(a[j]):
            a[i] = 'delete'

a = [i for i in a if i!= 'delete'] #new list without prefixed elements
```

Comment: What about cases where one string contains another but isn't a prefix, e.g. `private/etc/pam.d` and `fooprivate/etc/pam.d`. Also I don't think this works if `private/etc/pam.d` comes before `private` in the list.

Comment: Also what about if there is a string in the input with the value `'delete'`.

Comment: @Oli great questions, and I must confess I don't know the answers to them. For the first one you could check for if its in only the first half of the string, and for the second you could substitute delete for some random string of characters. if you have a more efficient solution please share it, Im genuinely interested in how to improve upon this

Comment: If I were to make minimal modifications to your code, I would use `a[i].startswith(a[j])` to solve the first problem (the method already exists, may as well use it!). To solve the second problem, either change the second for loop to `for j in range(len(a)):` and use an if statement to prevent comparing a list item with itself.

Comment: To prevent replacing items with 'delete', the safest option would be to use a second list of the same size to use to mark whether every item in the first list should be deleted or kept: declare list `keep_item = [True for i in range(len(a))]`, `if a[i].startswith(a[j]): keep_item[j] = False`, then `a = [item for item, keep in zip(a, keep_item) if keep]`

Answer (score -1):

I feel this can be solved by using sub-string, i.e. you are looking for a string which is not a sub-string of any other string.

Here is a solution in java, you can use same logic in python.

```
public static void findFullyQualifiedPaths() {

    List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    paths.add("private");
    paths.add("private/etc");
    paths.add("private/etc/pam.d");
    paths.add("usr");
    paths.add("usr/local");
    paths.add("usr/local/lib");
    paths.add("usr/local/lib/security");

    System.out.println("Input Paths");
    System.out.println(paths);

    List<String> filteredPaths = new ArrayList<String>(paths);

    filteredPaths.removeIf(currentPath -> {
        for (String path : paths) {
            if ((!path.equals(currentPath)) && path.contains(currentPath)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
    System.out.println("Paths after removing the substrings");
    System.out.println(filteredPaths);
}
```

Output:

```
Input Paths
[private, private/etc, private/etc/pam.d, usr, usr/local, usr/local/lib, usr/local/lib/security]
Paths after removing the substrings
[private/etc/pam.d, usr/local/lib/security]
```